# Calculating APY from N percent earned over X days

Tags: finance

What equation could I use to calculate the APY where percent interest and number of days are variable?

For instance, suppose I invested $100 and earned 10% interest in 5 days.

Comment: Do you mean 10% is earned each day (unlikely) or 10% per year "compounded daily" for 5 days?

Comment: I mean after 5 days 10% has been earned. So now I would be at $110 at the 5th day in this example.

Comment: 10% in 5 days would mean 100% in 50 days and considerably more in one year! That is unrealistic interest. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: This is just a simple example. I'm looking to figure out a flexible equation that can convert any variable interest rate over a variable period of days into an APY.

Comment: OK then one more question: For your example do you mean every 5 days the interest is 10% and you just want the interesst for 365 days? Then a simple proportion will work. If (a)% is earned every $d$ days, and you want the APY (call that $(x)$% per year), set it up as $a/d=x/365,$ It's easy to solve for $x$ here.

Comment: Yep, every 5 days interest earned is 10% ($110 after 5 days), or every 30 days interest earned is 5% ($105 after 30 days), etc etc.

Comment: Did you agree with my genera formula in last comment?

Comment: I think that should work. Also wondering what in the world happened to the spaces in my previous comment. :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139329/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-ecomevo).